# Any way to connect the leaf nodes via a line in d3.js collapsible tree layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treeview

```
           A
          /  \
         B    C
       / \   / \
      D  E   F  G
     /
    K
```

Now, K and E and K and F are associated. 
So, is there any way that I can add a line between these when the complete tree is made using the d3.js collapsible tree Layout.

Comment: the same as you draw the other links, find the leafs connected and draw some spline path to connect them

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can use the 'edit' link to amend your question to include the relevant details. You might consider using another visual aspect to show the relatedness of the nodes -- e.g. colour or shape. Extra lines will soon make the diagram complicated and confusing.